# What does the notation mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Given a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\upsilon)$ and a $p>0$.
What does the following mean?
$$ \|f\|_p=(\upsilon|f|^p)^{1/p}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they're trying to say:

$$
\|f\|_p=\left(\int_\Omega \vert f\vert^p dv\right)^{1/p}
$$  One way to justify their shorthand is that integration is like "measuring" the function, so $v\vert f\vert^p$ could be thought of as shorthand for $\int_\Omega\vert f\vert^pdv$.

Comment: Is $|f|^p$ the $p^{th}$ power of the absolute value of the function $f$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: so $|f|^p$ is another function, say, $g$, and $\upsilon|f|^p$ is the integral of $g$ with respect to $\upsilon$ ?

Comment: Correct, with the integration being over $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, for every measure $v$ and every integrable function $g$, one can use indifferently
$$
v(g),\qquad\int g\mathrm dv,\qquad\int_\Omega g(\omega)\mathrm dv(\omega),
$$
and a few other combinations of the above to denote the integral of the function $g$ with respect to the measure $v$. In particular,
$$
\|f\|_p=\left(\int_\Omega |f(\omega)|^p\mathrm dv(\omega)\right)^{1/p}=(v(|f|^p))^{1/p}.
$$